# How locally get data inside render() in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

```
fetchData(){
            let basicAccountData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basic"));  
}
```

/* This stores tha data in basicAccountData.I have stored data outside the render() method.But i'm bot able to access it inside render().When i'm storing it inside render() then it is giving error.Plzz. help me without using map().*/

Comment: Explain your problem better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the data from the fetchData function and use the function inside the render to access it.

```
fetchData() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basic"));
}

render() {
  const data = this.fetchData();

  // Do stuff with your data

  return (
    <div>{...}</div>
  );
}
```